# Treat object as another object

Tags: java, object, casting

First I would like to say this is a cosmetic only question, as you will understand right away.
I got an object, and I want that from now on, until I redecalre it, java will treat that object as another object, instead of me casting it again and again.
For example, I got something like this:

```
Object obj = new SomeObject();
((SomeObject) obj).someMethod1();
((SomeObject) obj).someMethod2();
((SomeObject) obj).someMethod3();
```

Instead, I would like to do something like:

```
Object obj = new SomeObject();
obj treatas SomeObject; // This is the line that I dont even know if exist in java
obj.someMethod1();
obj.someMethod2();
obj.someMethod3();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a new variable (or declare `obj` to be of `SomeObject` type in the first place):

```
Object obj = new SomeObject();
SomeObject sobj = (SomeObject) obj;
sobj.someMethod1();
sobj.someMethod2();
sobj.someMethod3();
```

And in the more general case, if you don't know for sure that `obj` is an instance of `SomeObject` :

```
if (obj instanceof SomeObject) {
    SomeObject sobj = (SomeObject) obj;
    sobj.someMethod1();
    sobj.someMethod2();
    sobj.someMethod3();
}
```

Comment: Well this is the answer I was looking for, I thought there is a way of doing that without creating a new var :\

Comment: @DanielPrizmant Well, there isn't. Since the `obj` variable can hold objects of any reference type, you can't use it to refer to methods of some specific class without first casting it to that class.